# Python : how to create list of single tuple?

Tags: python

i needed a list of only one tuple, like this`[(1,2,3,4,5,6)]`
, i tried this,

```
>>> [( i for i in range(1,10))]
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbf7ad94cd0>]
```

what is that generator object? How to use it?
how to generate this kind of list?

Comment: `[tuple(range(1,10))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

```
[tuple( i for i in range(1,10))]
```

`(i for i in something)` notation is called **Generator expression** in Python and returns a **generator object**. You are simply, capturing this object in `list`. See [PEP-289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), for more knowledge on **Generator Expressions**

Also, I am assuming, you plan to do much more than `i for i in range(1,10)`, as this is completely redundant, you can just as well do `[tuple(range(1,10))]`

Comment: @ajinkygadewar, would you like to accept the answer as well?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate it: `[tuple(range(1,10))]`. `tuple` already takes an iterable as argument, so it's useless to wrap `range` in a generator.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, missed one parenthesis?

Comment: @akshat yep sorry, typing too fast. Fixed.

Comment: @akshat yes, it is as per my need

Comment: @ajinkygadewar, this is what i meant [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)